# Using scanf for getting string

Tags: c

I'm beginner on c. I have this code which changes `e` character with `a` in given string

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *wordchange(char word[]){

    char *final = malloc(strlen(word) + 1); 


    int j = 0;
    while (word[j] != 0){
        if (word[j] == 'e'){
            final[j] = 'a';
        } else {
            final[j] = word[j];
        }
        j++;
    }

    return final;
}
int main(){
    printf(wordchange("Hello"));
}
```

How can I use `scanf` function in order to get string from user and use it in `wordchange` function

Comment: `char word[30]; sacnf("%29s", word)`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
char stringNAME[10];
scanf("%9s", stringNAME);
```

Comment: how can i declare the str?

Comment: char str[100]..like that

Comment: i use it like that but nothing appears when i execute it int main(){
    char stringNAME[10];
    scanf("%9s", stringNAME);
    printf(wordchange(stringNAME));
}

Comment: printf("%s",stringNAME);

Comment: but i should call wordchange function with given string

Comment: what is your wordchange function doing?? it should return string from the function and u should write printf("%s",worchange(stringName));

Comment: 1) The `"s"` is not needed in `scanf("%[^\t\n]s",str);`  2) `scanf("%[^\t\n]s",str);` will accept nothing if input begins with `'\n'` or `'\t'`, leaving `str` uninitialized and input still in `stdin`.